# How to get payment percentage from sage evolution database

Tags: sql-server, flowgear

How does PostAR link back to an invoice and which table holds the discount given on payments?

I know that invnum holds the invoice details

I'm looking for payments, as well as the discount given on payments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The PostAR table links to InvNum on PostAR.InvNumKey = InvNum.AutoIndex
- Correct, the invoice header information is on the InvNum table, while the invoice line details are on _btblInvoiceLines.
- Discount information is on the InvNum table for document level discounts, and _btblInvoiceLines for line level discounts